# java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /10.191.20.97:8080

Tags: java, android

I have connect java REST on local my computer(10.191.20.97:8080) I am making a android login app that is connecting to Java server. from browser i have successful connection with server but with android studio is somethings wrong:

```
I/System.out: port:8080
W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /10.191.20.97:8080
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:143)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:299)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:237)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
W/System.err:     at com.hpi.android.assetmanagement.ui.updateapk.MainCheckVersion$1GetDataJSON.doInBackground(MainCheckVersion.java:358)
W/System.err:     at com.hpi.android.assetmanagement.ui.updateapk.MainCheckVersion$1GetDataJSON.doInBackground(MainCheckVersion.java:334)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/Internet:  => false
D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: DecorView@d78cc18[], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@3577954
D/ViewRootImpl[MainCheckVersion]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=252KB, data=207KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=252KB, data=176KB
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x8f824000,api=1)
D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x8f824000)
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x8f823000,api=1)
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x8f823000,api=1)
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x8f823000,api=1)
D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = DecorView@67cfdda[]
D/WindowClient: Remove from mViews: DecorView@67cfdda[], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@3577954
```

Comment: Make sure your android phone can see your local computer in network layer.

Comment: problem is that the server in that address isn't available either because the pc isnt accepting connections which may be due to blocked connections by your firewalls in your pc assuming your device is in the same network as your pc.Also check that the address responds to ping requests from your device